# RAILS_ENV and rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i noted that in rails 2.3.2 there is no more option to set which rails environment you are using. So i cannot just set it anymore in environment.rb? There is any other way to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a command line argument.

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS INCORRECT!!!  It is an ENVIRONMENT variable which you can set in your shell:   RAILS_ENV -- see Terry's answer

Answer (score 3):

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

What exactly are you trying to run?  The rails generator?  A rake task? Mongrel?  I'm not sure this is actually a Rails issue.

Disclaimer: I haven't used 2.3.2, however.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean in `config/environment.rb`?

I'm 90% sure you can just add the line there if you need it. **And I'm wrong**, see VP's comment below. (Tested and confirmed it)

Comment: 90% sure? its not allowed anymore.. to be honest the server ignore it. You must pass it as a argument to the server

Answer (score 1):

im using rails 2.3.5 which should be similar to 2.3.2, and terry lorber is right,

RAILS_ENV=xyz  is the exact way to lauch rails stuff with RAILS_ENV specifified from command line.

In this way, you can use rake, script/console script/runner script/server etc. in your different environments

Answer (score 0):

define in config/environments/production.rb or development.rb or whatever other modes you are running like stage.rb instead of writing/defining in config/environment.rb

I am using it and its serving my purpose. don't use the keyword RAILS_ENV (I haven't tried it) 
I am using it APP_MODE = "Production" In production environment file and APP_MODE = "Development" in development file.

then you can use this in your application to detect which mode you are in.

Hope, I answer the question

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna run an application in development,

```
ruby script/server
```

To run in production,

```
ruby script/server -e production
```